# sending http request based on check frequency?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I wrote a working code that sends http request to websites and store the response code into the database. it is doing cool. but it one issue, before it sends http request, first it should check the check_frequency, if the check frequency is expired it should send the http request to that website otherwise, it should skip that website with out sending http request. my code is as follows

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Utilities\Reporter;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;
use App\Setting;
use Carbon;
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    private $default_check_frequency;

    protected $client;

    protected $reporter;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();

        $this->reporter = new Reporter;

        $this->default_check_frequency = Setting::defaultCheckFrequency();


    }

    private function addStatusToNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $resCode)
    {
        $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
            'values' => strval($resCode)
            ]);
    }

    private function report(Notification $notification, $resCode)
    {
     if(empty($resCode)){
        $resCode = "no response found";
    }

    if(Notification::health($resCode) !== 'up'){
        $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is down' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
            $notification->slack_channel);

        $this->reporter->mail($notification->email,$notification->website_url.' is down '. ' this is the status Code: '. $resCode);

    }else{
        $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is up' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
            $notification->slack_channel);
    }
}

private function sendNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $status_health, $frequency, $resCode)
{
    $notify = empty($status_health['timestamp']);
    $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();



    if ($notify || $elapsed_time >= $frequency) {
        $this->addStatusToNotification($notification, $status, $resCode);
    }
    if(Notification::health($resCode) ==='up'){              
        if(Notification::health($resCode) <> Notification::health($status_health['value'])){  
        var_dump("1",Notification::health($resCode),Notification::health($status_health['value']));             
            $this->report($notification, $resCode);  
        }             
    }else{
        if(Notification::health($resCode) <> Notification::health($status_health['value'])){
             var_dump("2",Notification::health($resCode),Notification::health($status_health['value']));
            $this->report($notification, $resCode);
        }else{
            if($notify || $elapsed_time >= $notification->alert_frequency){
             $this->report($notification, $resCode);  
         }
     }  
 } 
}


public function status()
{
    $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();

    $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
    }
}

private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
{
    $resCode = $this->getStatusCode($notification->website_url);

    $this->sendNotification(
        $notification,
        $status,
        $notification->status('health'),
        $this->getFrequency($notification,$resCode),
        $resCode
        );
}

private function getFrequency(Notification $notification) 
{           

    return isset($notification->check_frequency)
    ? intval($notification->check_frequency)
    : $this->default_check_frequency;                
}

private function getStatusCode($url)
{
    try {   
         // add here the check frequency thing before sending http request    
        $response = $this->client->get($url, [
            'http_errors' => false
            ]);
        return $response->getStatusCode();  
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {   

    }
    }
}
```

iam trying to figure out where to make a check. if the elapsed time is greater than the check frequency, send http request, if not skip that website. i would apperciate any help?

Comment: I've just read til 'perfect code'

Comment: @gbestard same XD

Comment: I want to write a perfect code...

Comment: i dont mean it prefect, i mean it is  working code. sorry for that.

Comment: Before `$this->updateStatus` ? What you are actually asking? It doesn't seem related to guzzle nor laravel.

Comment: @Alex Blex, before this->updateStatus, in the status function. I am looping through all notifications( the website urls) in the database, because i have a model called Notification.

Comment: Yes, I get it. I am asking what stops you to check it there in the loop and call  `$this->updateStatus` only when your condition meets? If your question was "*where to make a check*", the answer is right there, unless you have any concerns.